# TileOverlay: getTile() breakpoint never hit

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use the new class `TileProvider` ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider)) that comes in Google Maps v2.  I've set up a really simple class:

```
/** This class provides images for WeatherOverlay **/
public static class RadarProvider implements TileProvider 
{

    /** Public constructor, provide default square dimensions **/
    public RadarProvider(int width, int height) 
    {
        //super(width, height);
    }

    public Tile getTile(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2) 
    {
        /* Breakpoint here */ return null;
    }

}
```

(It's a static class because it's nested inside of another class.)

I've put a breakpoint in the method `getTile()` at the line `return null`, but it's never hit.  I expected that as the map loaded tiles, it would call this method to retreive my custom tiles, but it was never called (or at least the breakpoint never tripped).  I am running in debug mode.  Here is the code where I add the provider to the map:

```
 RadarProvider radarProvider = new WeatherOverlay.RadarProvider(256,256);
 TileOverlayOptions options = new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(radarProvider);
 TileOverlay tileOverlay = map.addTileOverlay(options);
```

I'm not getting any exceptions when I run that code, so I'm assuming that the `TileProvider` is added correctly.  Any ideas as to why the method `getTile()` isn't getting called?

Comment: I've run your example and method getTile() was called. I tested it with breakpoint and android.util.Log. Can you show full code?

Comment: Agreed with paha, can't find any obvious error.

Comment: If you have simplified your code, and the problem was that the original code showed no tile, please read this issue https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4995 
The call from android to getTile absorbes most runtime exceptions, and some java.lang.error as well, so you won't see any error your code is firing in this function unless you surround your code with try/catch and print the errors yourself.